# Select unique tuple of rows with specific conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider a table called `HotelBooking` containing 2 columns: `email` and `dateOfBooking`.

How do I return all unique tuples (so 2 columns: `email1` and `email2`) that made at least one booking on exactly 1 same dateOfBooking. This means I do not want to return any tuples that made at least one booking on the same day but on multiple occasions.

A starting point:

```
SELECT hb1.email AS email1, hb2.email AS email2, hb1.dateofbooking 
FROM hotelbooking hb1
INNER JOIN hotelboeking hb2 USING (email, tijdstip)
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

First we group all the emails per common dateOfBooking, and we only keep the groups with more than one email (first clause `HAVING count(*) > 1`).
Then we calculate all the binomes (email1, email2) within a same group (,both clauses `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`) we regroup by (email1,email2) and keep only the binomes which have more than 1 common dateOfBooking (second clause `HAVING count(*) > 1`).

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT dateOfBooking
     , array_agg(email) AS email_array
  FROM HotelBooking 
 GROUP BY dateOfBooking
HAVING count(*) > 1
)
SELECT email1, email2
     , count(*) AS common_dates_count
     , array_agg(dateOfBooking) AS common_dates
  FROM list AS l
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(email_array) AS email1
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(email_array) AS email2
 WHERE email1 <> email2
 GROUP BY email1, email2
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.

get JSON value

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY((SELECT hb1.email AS email1, hb2.email AS email2 FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) email, hb1.dateofbooking 
FROM hotelbooking hb1
INNER JOIN hotelboeking hb2 USING (email, tijdstip)
```